# Animation of image through layoutIfNeeded stopped working

Tags: swift, animatewithduration

I have encountered an issue that's really confusing to me. I wrote a simple animation of two images to move and it worked perfectly. However all sudden it stopped animate and I can't figure out why. I haven't made any changes I can think of that would effect the animation. I have checked that the NSLayoutConstraints are actually being updated and they are, but it's not being animated.. Any ideas would be more than appreciated.

Unfortunately I don't have any git versions. I'm a bit of a newbie and at least this experience thought me of the value of git and I will use it henceforth. I have added constraints in the storyboard, four of them would be the ones I try to affect through the code. They are the y and x constraint for the two images I try to move.

**Additional information** I have four warnings saying: Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration. Turn off this constraint in the current configuration. I have been able to conclude that the constraints giving the warnings are the four constraints I'm trying to animate. But I'm still unsure how to fix this.

**Additional update**
I have now moved the animation code to `override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { super.viewWillAppear(true)`. After doing that I actually see the animation if I remove the first `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` However it animates all the views. But I can't get only the constraint changes to animate still.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

...

```
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.firstCallyC?.constant = 0

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.3, delay: 0.3, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.firstCallyC!.constant = (usePoint[0].y) - 210
        self.firstCallxC?.constant = (usePoint[0].x) - 300
        self.meditateyC?.constant = (usePoint[179].y) - 210
        self.meditatexC?.constant = (usePoint[179].x) - 300
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code to only include the most pertinent - no one wants to read through your whole class to debug it. Also, do you have `git` versions that might help you find why things changed? And are you setting any constraints in a storyboard or changed anything there?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have edited my query. Ask more if you can think of additional information that would be helpful.

Comment: just call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() on animations block

Comment: And is that not what I'm doing in the code above? @Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution by adding a `override func viewDidAppear` to the class and then adding the animation to that function. I guess all the images need to be properly loaded and placed before they can be animated or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

you should constraints constants out of animation block

```
  firstCallyC!.constant = (usePoint[0].y) - 210
  firstCallxC?.constant = (usePoint[0].x) - 300
  meditateyC?.constant = (usePoint[179].y) - 210
  meditatexC?.constant = (usePoint[179].x) - 300
  UIView.animateWithDuration(1.3, delay: 0.3, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that already and it doesn't help unfortunately. @Coyote It seems to me like the layout already has been updated and that's why the animation dosen't happen. I tested it by deleting both self.view.layoutIfNeeded() and the images appeared at their updated positions anyway.. That's weird isn't it?

Comment: yes it's.but  I stay believe the recommended way to animate a view with constraint is to change constraint and then you update layout with `layouIfNeeded()`. You can try view transformation it can help https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/

Comment: Yeah layoutIf Needed worked perfectly once I got it right. I found a solution finally by moving the code to `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidload`.